# glGetProgramInfoLog returning empty string while glGetProgramiv claims that the program did not successfully link

Tags: opengl, c++

I am currently trying to write a basic program using OpenGL 3.3, and I am encountering an issue: glGetProgramInfoLog is returning an empty string while glGetProgramiv is saying that there is an error when linking my shader program.

The problematic code follows:

```
//load shaders
GLuint vertexShader = loadShader("shader.vert", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint fragmentShader = loadShader("shader.frag", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

//link program
programId = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(programId, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(programId);

//check for errors
GLint success = 5; //for debugging to make sure it wasn't 0 by default and glGetProgramiv wasn't writing to it
glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
if(!success){
    GLchar infoLog[1024];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to link OpenGl shader program material: ") + infoLog);
}

//delete shaders
glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
```

When I attempt to run my program, the runtime_error is thrown with the following termination message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Failed to link OpenGl shader program material:
```

I confirmed through my debugger that the `success` variable is bring written to (see comment in code), and that glGetProgramInfoLog is writing the first byte of infoLog to all zeroes, thus making it a null-terminated string of length 0.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Information:
GPU: Nvidia GTX 1070
OS: Ubuntu Linux 17.10 x64
Display server: Xorg
Driver version: 384.111 (latest in official Ubuntu repositories)
Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0
Kernel Version: 4.13.0-25-generic
Windowing Library: SFML version 2.4.2+dfsg-4 (as described [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-opengl.php)) (version from apt-cache policy command)

Things I have tried:

- Modifying error checking code to check `GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH`, which returns 0 despite GL_LINK_STATUS returning GL_FALSE (also 0.
- Compiling the program and testing on Windows 10 running on the same hardware, since I don't have access to any sufficiently different gpu for better testing, in an attempt to rule out a driver error that may only exist on Linux. The same thing happens on Windows.

I have also posted this question to reddit, where no useful answers came up ([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/7ponw4/glgetprograminfolog_returning_empty_string_while/)).

Full program source:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void init();
void update();

GLuint loadShader(const std::string &shaderPath, GLenum shaderType);

sf::Window window;
GLuint programId;
GLuint vbo, vao, ebo;

int main(){
    init();
    while(true){
        update();
    }
}

void init(){
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 0;
    settings.majorVersion = 3;
    settings.minorVersion = 3;

    window.create(sf::VideoMode(1600, 900), "PerlinGl", sf::Style::Default, settings);
    window.setActive(true);

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize GLEW.");
    }

    //load shaders
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader("shader.vert", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = loadShader("shader.frag", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    //link program
    programId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programId, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(programId);

    //check for errors
    GLint success = 5;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to link OpenGl shader program material: ") + infoLog);
    }

    //delete shaders
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    //setup "mesh"
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    GLuint indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), reinterpret_cast<void*>(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

void update(){
    sf::Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event)){
        switch(event.type){
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                std::terminate();
                break;
        }
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    window.display();
}

GLuint loadShader(const std::string &shaderPath, GLenum shaderType){
    //load source
    std::ifstream fin(shaderPath);
    std::ostringstream sout;

    while(fin){
        std::string line;
        std::getline(fin, line);
        sout << line << std::endl;
    }

    std::string shaderSource = sout.str();
    const char *shaderSourceCString = shaderSource.c_str();

    std::cout << "Shader source: " << shaderSource << std::endl;

    //create shader
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderSourceCString, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    //test for errors
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to compile OpenGl shader (" + shaderPath + "): " + infoLog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the error (I should have turned on compiler warnings. that would have saved a lot of trouble). It turned out I was missing a return statement in my `loadShader` function. I finally found it by comparing line-by-line to a working piece of code on the Internet.